# Curvature operator of a Kähler manifold with constant holomorphic sectional curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds

A Riemannian metric $g$ on a manifold $M$ induces a pointwise inner product on $\Lambda^2 (TM)$, given on decomposable elements by
$$
\langle X\wedge Y, Z\wedge T \rangle
= g(X,Z) g(Y,T) - g(X,T) g(Y,Z),
$$
and then extended by linearity.
Due to its symmetries, the Riemann curvature tensor $R$ induces the so-called curvature operator $\mathcal{R}$, defined by
$$
\langle \mathcal{R}(X\wedge Y), Z\wedge T \rangle
= R(X,Y,Z,T),
$$
which is a symmetric operator.
Here I used the convention that the sectional curvature of an orthonormal couple $\{u,v\}$ is $R(u,v,u,v)$.
It is a very well known fact that a Riemannian manifold has constant sectional curvature $\kappa$ if and only if the curvature tensor reads
$$
R(X,Y,Z,T)
= \kappa\big(g(X,Z) g(Y,T) - g(X,T) g(Y,Z) \big),
$$
that is, if and only if the associated curvature operator is $\mathcal{R} = \kappa \,\mathrm{Id}_{\Lambda^2(TM)}$.

In the realm of Kähler geometry, it is also known that a Kähler manifold has constant holomorphic sectional curvature if and only if the curvature tensor is given by
\begin{align}
R(X,Y,Z,T)
&= \frac{\kappa}{4} \big(g(X,Z)g(Y,T)-g(X,T)g(Y,Z) \\
& \quad + g(JX,Z)g(JY,T) -g(JX,T)g(JY,Z) + 2g(JX,Y)g(JZ,T) \big).
\end{align}
Through the scope of the curvature operator $\mathcal{R}$, it appears that the holomorphic sectional curvature is constant equal to $\kappa$ if and only if
$$
\mathcal{R}
= \frac{\kappa}{4}\left(\mathrm{Id}_{\Lambda^2(TM)} + \bar{J} + A \right)
$$
where $\bar{J}(X\wedge Y) = (JX)\wedge (JY)$ and $A$ satisfies
$$
\langle A(X\wedge Y), Z\wedge T\rangle
= 2g(JX,Y)g(JZ,T)
= g(JX,Y)g(JZ,T) + g(X,JY)g(Z,JT).
$$

My question is the following:
Is there any nice algebraic expression for $A(X\wedge Y)$ solely in terms of $X$, $Y$, and $J$?

Due to the presence of mixed terms between $X$ and $Y$ as well as the complex structure $J$ in the $(Z,T)$ entries of $\langle A(X\wedge Y), Z\wedge T\rangle$, it is somewhat non trivial to find such an algebraic expression.
Note that $\bar{J}^2 = \mathrm{Id}_{\Lambda^2(TM)}$, which I interpret as (part of) the $J$-symmetric part of the curvature.
My intuition is that $A$ shall be the $J$-anti-symmetric part of the curvature, and such an algebraic expression should then involve $(JX)\wedge Y$ and $X\wedge (JY)$, but my computations are somewhat leading nowhere.